# Pagination issues with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, pagination

I have the following html binding in knockout

```
<div data-bind="with: talkData">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Talks">
        <p data-bind="text: Title"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    <button class="btn btn-success previous" 
            data-bind="click: $root.PageBack, disable: $root.page() == 1">Prev</button>                         
    <button class="btn btn-success next" 
            data-bind="click: $root.PageNext, disable: $root.page() == $root.talkData().TotalPageCount">Next</button>
</p>
```

With the following model:

```
$(function() {
    function TalksViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.page = ko.observable(1);
        self.records = ko.observable(1);
        self.totalPages = ko.observable(1);
        self.talkData = ko.observable();

        self.IsPrevEnabled = isPrevEnabled;

        function pageBack(item) {
            self.page(self.page() - 1);
            loadDataFromServer();
        }

        self.PageBack = pageBack;

        function pageNext(item) {
            console.log("page next");
            self.page(self.page() + 1);
            loadDataFromServer();
        }

        self.PageNext = pageNext;

        function loadDataFromServer() {
            var url = '/Talks/GetPagedTalks';
            self.talkData(null);
            $.get(url, { page: self.page() }, self.talkData);
        }

        // Initial page
        loadDataFromServer();        
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new TalksViewModel());
});
```

The JSON returned from the 'GetPagedTalks' call is:

```
Talks: [{Title:Philippians 1:12-26,…}, {Title:Philippians 1:1-11,…}, {Title:Devoted   Lives: ,…}]
0: {Title:Philippians 1:12-26,…}
1: {Title:Philippians 1:1-11,…}
2: {Title:Devoted Lives: ,…}
TotalPageCount: 59
TotalRowCount: 177
```

The next and previous buttons work but I'm really struggling to know how to set the total number of pages from the data returned from the GET call.

The line:
   disable: $root.page() == $root.talkData().TotalPageCount

Isn't working at all.  I assumed TotalPageCount would be part of talkData.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get set the data (values and page count) try this:

```
$.get(url, { page: self.page() })
 .done(function(data){
    self.talkData(data);
    self.totalPages(data.TotalPageCount);
    self.records(data.TotalRowCount);
})
.fail(function(xhr,status,error){
  // handle any error here
});
```

In this particular case - I used the get promise 'done' to get the data. Check the jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)  - they have some additional samples for the way in which you can use/consume the return parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This post is very old but if anyone having the same problem, you can implement pagination in a very simple way without worrying about its' internals. 
 (here http://contractnamespace.blogspot.com/2014/02/pagination-with-knockout-jquery.html).

Basically, I have used normal knockout data binding with AJAX and after data has been retrieved from the server, I call the plugin. You can find the plugin here. [its called Simple Pagination](http://contractnamespace.blogspot.com/2014/02/pagination-with-knockout-jquery.html).